# How to /give a player a named item with Level 10 enchants in Pocket/Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m building a multiplayer hide-and-seek map, and I want to give seekers an instant-kill weapon named “Boop Stick” (don’t ask).

```
/give @p leather_boots 1 0 {display:{Name:"Boop Stick",Lore:["Boop! You're dead."]},ench:[{sharpness:10}{knockback:10}]}
```

[image: a screenshot of code in a MCPE command block.]

(note that I’m using a placeholder item in the image)

I keep getting errors like this:

```
Line 1, Column 2
Missing '}' or object member name
```

[image: a screenshot of a MCPE error message]

How do I fix this in a compact manner (ie easy to hide the command blocks)?

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed a problem similar to this when I was trying to do commands to give sticks, wooden pickaxes, and shovels sharpness and knock-back enchantments.

It seems like there's a either a glitch or a parity issue where unlike Java Edition, Bedrock Edition has a set specific limit on the kinds of enchantments that are allowed for certain items (for ex: pickaxes are allowed to have efficiency and fortunate, the intended enchantments, but they aren't allowed to have sharpness or knock-back, the types of enchantments that Bedrock Edition decided would be exclusively for weapon-type tools), and if you try to force the enchantments that aren't allowed for a certain item, then you'll just get an error.

It looks like you're trying to give leather boots a sharpness enchantment which isn't allowed in Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but you can "give" a named/enchanted item by cloning a chest that has the item you want. Store the chest in a safe place and then clone it somewhere nearby the player you wish to give it to.